# scrapy crawl [spider-name] fault

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

Hi guys i am building a web scraping project using scrapy framework and python.
In spider folder of my project i have two spiders named spider1 and spider2

spider1.py

```
class spider(BaseSpider):
    name= "spider1"
    ........
    ........
```

spider2.py

```
class spider(BaseSpider):
    name="spider2"
    ............
    ...........
```

settings.py

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['project_name.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = ['project_name.spiders']
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['project_name.pipelines.spider']
```

Now when i write the command `scrapy crawl spider1` in my root project folder it calls spider2.py instead of spider1.py. when i will delete spider2.py from my project then it calls spider1.py

Earlier 1 day back its working fine for 1 month but suddenly what happens i can't figure it out please help me guys

Comment: What happens when you rename the classes, i.e. change `class spider(BaseSpider):...` to `class Spider1(BaseSpider):...` in spider1.py and `class Spider2(BaseSpider):...` in spider2.py?

Comment: Nothing happens if i change the class name in both spiders

Comment: Try clearing all *.pyc files and _ensure_ you have given the spiders different names in the 'name' attribute.

Comment: i have tried cleaning all *.pyc file

Comment: 1 more strange thing is happening @Sjaak . I have cleaned spider1.pyc ,spider2.pyc and _init_.pyc. Now when i run `scrapy crawl spider1` in my root flder of project it actually runs spider2.py but spider1.pyc file is generated instead of spider2.pyc

Comment: Something in spider2.py must be mixed up; does it by accident import or inherit from spider1?

Comment: Update your question with the actual spider code.

Comment: Actually the problem is solved in a way. I dont know why it is hapening but i have made a way out. If i moving my scrapy project to new env. and then whenever i used to run `scrapy crawl spider1` `spider2.py` is get called. So i temporarily deleted `spider2.py` code from my project. Then i tried to run `scrapy crawl spider1` it runs finely `spider1.py`. Now i have included the spider2.py code in my scrapy project. Now when i run`scrapy crawl spider1` `spider1` is called.  So my problem is solved, but i dont know Why ?

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth Can you please help me in understanding this behavior of scrapy

Comment: you would have to post all your for the entire project somewhere, preferably zipped up into a single file

Answer (score 1):

I tackled the same problem, however removing all *.pyc files from everywhere in my project did the job.

Especially I think settings.pyc is important to remove.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Nomad's answer.
You can avoid the creation of all but one pyc file during development by adding:

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
```

to the project's "**__init__.py**" file.

This will prevent *.pyc* files from being created. Especially useful if you are working on a project and you rename the file name of a spider. Prevents the cached pyc of the old spiders remaining, and a few other gotchas.