# Scrapy crawling all my spiders at once

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm encountering a weird Scrapy bug that just cropped up today for seemingly no good reason. It seems to be similar to the bug documented here: [scrapy crawl [spider-name] fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992051/scrapy-crawl-spider-name-fault), but I could not fix it with the solutions suggested there. Basically, I have multiple spiders (spider1, spider2 etc.) all with different names in the same project, but when I ask Scrapy to start a specific spider as such:

```
scrapy crawl spider1
```

scrapy begins to execute ALL of the spiders in my spiders folder. I have tried to start a new project and the same issue occurs. Appreciate any help!

Scrapy version is the latest 1.03, on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Please add some system info: scrapy version, OS type

Comment: Sorry about that,  edited.